# How do i merge specific parts of an associative array?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, mysqli

Question first, explanation later:

Insteat of the first array, i want one which looks like the secound array:

```
echo json_encode($movies);
//WHAT I DO NOT WANT: [{"movie_name":"test1","genre_name":"Action"},{"movie_name":"test2","genre_name":"Drama"},{"movie_name":"test2","genre_name":"Action"}]
//WHAT I WANT: [{"movie_name":"test1","genres":["Action"]},{"movie_name":"test2","genres":["Drama","Action"]}]
```

So insteat of severals rows with the same value for movie_name but different values for genre_name, i want one row for each movie, where all genre_names are merged into one gernes array;

The solution i wish:
The data is fetched from an database using php and mysqli. This is the SQL query i use and which generates the first array:

```
SELECT movies.movie_name, genres.genre_name FROM genres
 INNER JOIN genre_movie ON genres.id = genre_movie.genre_id 
 INNER JOIN movies ON movies.id = genre_movie.movie_id;
```

I am not good with SQL and think there is a query which gets the me the secound array (the one I WANT) right away.

My solution so far:
i actually solved the problem using a php arglorithm, but its kinda complecated and hard if the anything scales or i add new columns:

```
foreach($myArray as $movie)
{
    foreach($newList as $key => $item)
    {
        if($item['movie_name'] == $movie['movie_name']){
            $exists = true;
            $position = $key;
        }
    }
    if($exists == true)
    {
        $newList[$position]['genres'][] = $movie['genre_name'];
        $exists= false;

    } else {
        $newList[] = array('movie_name' => $movie['movie_name'], 'genres' => array($movie['genre_name']));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at group_concat: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

I didn't emulate your tables but maybe this is your query:

```
SELECT movies.movie_name, group_concat(genres.genre_name) FROM genres
INNER JOIN genre_movie ON genres.id = genre_movie.genre_id 
INNER JOIN movies ON movies.id = genre_movie.movie_id
GROUP BY movies.movie_name;
```

**Edition**

Well, I emulated it now, and yes, it's your query. I would just change:

```
group_concat(genres.genre_name)
```

For:

```
group_concat(distinct(genres.genre_name))
```

To return only different values.

Comment: This works great, but the array key is named group_concat(genres.genre_name), what is a good way to change this? **EDIT:** just had to add AS new_name